# android how to add separator in headerlayout?

Tags: android

I want to add separator in between button and textview in my layout header contains 2 buttons and textview how do I add separator in between them?

```
<RelativeLayout 
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="50px"
 android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
 android:background="@color/Blue" 
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/Back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:background="@color/Blue" 
    android:textSize="20sp" 
    android:textColor="@color/White" 
    android:text=" Back"
   />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Exit"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Back"
    android:textSize="20sp" 
    android:textStyle="italic" 
    android:typeface="serif" 
    android:background="@color/Blue" 
    android:textColor="@color/White" 
    android:text="Games Apps"/>

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/Exit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:textSize="20sp" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@color/Blue" 
    android:textColor="@color/White" 
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text=" Exit"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

add View between your button and textview

For instance

```
<View 
    android:layout_width="2dip"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/header_text"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Exit"
    android:padding = "5dip"
    android:background="#FFFF0000"
/>
```

Comment: i want to add seprater like this way button|textview|button

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you need a vertical separator:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="2dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/header_text"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/Back"
    android:background="#00000000"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

May this help you..

To add seperator you have to add a view in between the objects you want seperator..

like..

```
<View 
     android:layout_width="2dip"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/header_text"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Back"
     android:padding = "5dip"
     android:background="#FFFF0000"
/>
```

and change this lines in your code..

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Exit"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Back"
    android:textSize="20sp" 
    android:textStyle="italic" 
    android:typeface="serif" 
    android:background="@color/Blue" 
    android:textColor="@color/White" 
    android:text="Games Apps"/>
```

or you can use `<TableRow> </TableRow>` try to put the whole code with seperator in between the views

Answer (score 0):

Try this, just workaround worked for me. You can use the same logic by implementing other Layout to instead of TableLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   >



        <TableLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:stretchColumns="*"
                android:showDividers="middle"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:background="#000000"
                android:divider="#000000"
                >

            <TableRow>

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Back"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:text=" Back"
                        />


                <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/header_text"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Exit"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Back"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                        android:textStyle="italic"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:typeface="serif"
                        android:text="Games Apps"/>

                <Button
                        android:id="@+id/Exit"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                        android:background="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:text=" Exit"
                        />



            </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know you have other difficulties use this.