# how to add separator in header layout

Tags: android

How do i add a separator in header layout?

This is my layout screenshot  [image: http://postimg.org/image/j6p1s67w7/4214ab6d/]

Please help me how do i add a separator in backbutton textview and exit button below is my full xml code just tell me how do i add sreprater???

```
                       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com
  /apk/res   /android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
 <RelativeLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="50px"
android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
  android:background="@color/Blue" 
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Back"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
       android:background="@color/Blue" 
         android:textSize="20sp" 
android:textColor="@color/White" 
    android:text=" Back"
   />


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header_text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center" 
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Exit"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Back"

android:textSize="20sp" 
android:textStyle="italic" 
android:typeface="serif" 
android:background="@color/Blue" 
android:textColor="@color/White" 
android:text="Games Apps"/>
<View 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="2dip"
android:layout_below="@id/header_text"
android:layout_above="@id/Exit"
android:background="#FFFF0000"
 />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Exit"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:textSize="20sp" 
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       android:background="@color/Blue" 
android:textColor="@color/White" 
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:text=" Exit"
    />

  </RelativeLayout>

 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical" >

 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/appslist"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>


 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i just only want to add seprater in between button and textview in header what do ido??

Comment: this post not helping me    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17483083/android-how-to-add-seprater-in-headerlayout

Comment: First of all remove background color to your parent relative layout, second add background colour to all child views, Third add margin between your child views..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="60px"
 android:background="#0000FF"
 android:id="@+id/relalayout"
 android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
 >

<Button
android:id="@+id/Back"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:text=" Back"
android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
android:id="@+id/header_text"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center" 
 android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:textSize="20sp" 
  android:textStyle="italic" 
 android:typeface="serif" 
 android:text="Games Apps"/>
 <Button
 android:id="@+id/Exit"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:textSize="20sp" 
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
android:text=" Exit"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
 <LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
 android:id="@+id/listlayout"
 android:layout_below="@+id/relalayout"
 >
 <ListView
  android:id="@+id/appslist"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
  </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why u use this line two times??

Comment: down vote accept
 

try the following code

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

Comment: ur layout will be good i need same as this but what is this
 android1:layout??
android1:layout_width="wrap_content"

Comment: u used 4 times width and height

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android1:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

Comment: Thst's Just Typing Mistake

Comment: Just change text colors and fonts as u wish

Comment: thnk u so much is really helping me. is same is what i want